# variable for input value isn't behaving as expected in JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a project. I'm creating a canvas that can be manipulated by the user. There are currently 3 input fields for the user to select Height, Width, and a 3rd value called "space".

Currently, Height and Width seem to work perfect fine, but the Space input isn't behaving as expected. For "Space" the user should be able to enter a value between 15 and 50. (space represents the distance between the circles I'm drawing).

The loop for drawing the circles is:

```
const lightsTop = function () {
  for (let i = 5; i < cw; i += space) {
    let randX = Math.random() * 10;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(i, 5 + randX, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fill();
  }
};
```

This code (above) works perfectly fine if I manually put in "15" (or some arbitrary number between 15-50). It generates a row of circles (which eventually will act like a string of lights), but when I use the variable "space", then it only generates 1 circle.

Here is the full JS: (the HTML is just the 3 inputs `type="number"`,ids = #width, #height, #space)

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");
const widthInput = document.querySelector("#width");
const heightInput = document.querySelector("#height");
const spaceInput = document.querySelector("#space");
let cw = 500;
let ch = 300;
let space = 15;
canvas.width = cw;
canvas.height = ch;

widthInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  cw = widthInput.value;
  if (cw < 200) cw = 200;
  if (cw > 1000) cw = 1000;
  canvas.width = cw;
  lightsTop();
});

heightInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  ch = heightInput.value;
  if (ch < 200) ch = 200;
  if (ch > 600) ch = 600;
  canvas.height = ch;
  lightsTop();
});

spaceInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  space = spaceInput.value;
  if (space < 15) space = 15;
  if (space > 50) space = 50;
  animate();
});

function animate() {
    c.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    requestAnimationFrame(lightsTop);
}

const lightsTop = function () {
  for (let i = 5; i < cw; i += space) {
    let randX = Math.random() * 10;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(i, 5 + randX, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.fill();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a string to the variable:

```
 space = spaceInput.value;
```

It must be a number

```
 space = parseInt(spaceInput.value);
```

Comment: That worked 100%. I guess I thought that because the `type="number"` in HTML it would automatically be a number (int). Thank you. I have to wait 10mins before i can mark your answer.